# NPM start on window getting $npm_package_config_TSNODE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have already written code. I have downloaded the code on Window and Linux

and run following commonds

```
npm cache clean --force
npm i 
npm install
```

My application is running fine on Linux but i am getting error on windows

> $npm_package_config_TSNODE run/start
>
> '$npm_package_config_TSNODE' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command, operable program or batch file. npm ERR! code
> ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! @ start:
> `$npm_package_config_TSNODE run/start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
> problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Any idea how to fix this issue on Window machine.

Comment: It probably related to the dollar prefix `$` in this line of code: `$npm_package_config_TSNODE` - which I assume is part of your npm script(s). The dollar prefix `$` is the syntax used on *nix to reference variables (an environment variable in this scenario). On windows the syntax to reference a variable is to encase in `%...%` characters. For example:  `%npm_package_config_TSNODE%` - Consider utilizing the [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) package for one script syntax that works cross-platform.